# hashcat [CommandLine Error: Option 'polly' registered more than once! & LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options]

Tags: hashcat

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/Compressed/hashcat-6.0.0# ./hashcat.bin -I
hashcat (v6.0.0) starting...

: CommandLine Error: Option 'polly' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

I don't know how to fix this?

Comment: Have the same issue, when running anything that is using OpenCL. `clinfo` also only returns the same two last lines as above.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu (or a variant of it)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Libre Office, or roll it back to a previous version.
I don't know the finer details, but I noticed the current version has a bug that seems to interfere with OpenCL compatible software.

Not an ideal solution, but it's all I got at the moment.
My only clue was [this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/259230/libreoffice-wont-start-on-linux/).